# encode decode binary data

Tags: binary, ascii, decode, encode

I know the binary value "1000001" when converted to decimal is 65, which according to ASCII table is letter A.

Now, I have a binary file(xxx.bin) suppose with above sequence of bits. How do i know whether tat binary value is meant to represent the decimal value 65 or the character A??

I suppose when i received the binary file, I should have also known what character encoding or char set doc does this binary file follows? or can I find out somehow  how it was encoded??

Can someone clear up how a binary file(xxx.bin) data can be decoded properly and read? just convert each byte to decimal value or follow some char encoding logic??? I am confused on this part!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a program that I made to encode a string into 'dots' and 'spaces'. It can also decode it back to the original string if the code is provide. try it yourself. there is a encode_find() function in it, which converts a character into its binary equivalent and stores it in the variable 'en'. the reverse process can be achieved decode_find() function.

```
import java.io.*;
class ed2
{

BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

void encode()throws InterruptedException,IOException
{
    String rs,ren;

    encoder_symbol();
    rs = encode_input();
    ren = encode_find(rs);
    encode_display(ren);
}

void decode()throws InterruptedException,IOException
{
    String rs,rde;

    decoder_symbol();
    rs = decode_input();
    rde = decode_find(rs);
    decode_display(rde);
}

void encoder_symbol()throws InterruptedException //just for fun
{
    System.out.println("********  ***         ***  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********  ****        ***  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       *****       ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       *** **      ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******    ***  **     ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******    ***   **    ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       ***     **  ***  ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***       ***      ** ***  ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("*******   ***       *****  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("*******   ***        ****  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
    Thread.sleep(2700);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

void decoder_symbol()throws InterruptedException // just for fun
{
    System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ******    ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ******    *****");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***    ***  ***       ***        ***      ***  ***    ***  ***       *** **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("***   ***   ***       ***        ***      ***  ***   ***   ***       ***  **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("********    ********  *********  ************  ********    ********  ***   **");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("******      ********  *********  ************  ******      ********  ***    **");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

String encode_input()throws IOException
{
    String s;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE STRING TO BE ENCODED");
    s = obj.readLine();
    return(s);
}

String decode_input()throws IOException
{
    String s;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE CODE TO BE DECODED");
    s = obj.readLine();
    return(s);
}

String encode_find(String s)//converting the string into its binary equivalent
{
     int ac,i,j,l,chklen;
     String bc,en="";
     char ic;
     l = s.length();    
     for(i=0;i<l;i++)
     {   
         ic = s.charAt(i); //takes out every character
         bc = ""; 
         ac = (int)ic;  //ASCII value of this character
         while(ac!=0)
         {
             bc = Integer.toString((ac%2)) + bc; //converting the ASCII value into binary equivalent
             ac = ac/2;
         }
         chklen = bc.length();//length of the binary equivalent
         if(chklen<7)
         {
            for(j=1;j<=(7-chklen);j++) //increasing the length of binary equivalent so that it becomes equal to 7
            {  
                bc = "0" + bc;
            }
         }
         en = en+bc; //concatenating all the binary equivalent into one string
     }
     return (en);
}

String decode_find(String s)// converts binary(i.e. in the form of dots and space) to decimal
{
    int f;//for the index of every character of code
    long l,i,j,ac;
    char c;
    String de="";

    l = s.length();
    f = 0;//index of first caharcter
    for(i=0;i<(l/7);i++)//since the length of every binary equivalent of a character is 7 therefore there will be (length/7) characters in a code of length l
    {
        ac = 0;//intializes the decimal(ASCII) equivalent to zero
        for(j=6;j>=0;j--)//loop will work 7 times for every binary equivalent of a character
        {
            c = s.charAt(f);//takes out every dot or space
            if(c=='.')//it means that c corresponds to 'one'
            {
                ac = ac + ((int)Math.pow(2,j));//converting binary into decimal(ASCII) equivalent by adding all the powers of 2 which correspond to one('.') 
            }
            f++;//increasing the index for next character of binary equivalent
        }
        de = de + ((char)ac);//converts the ASCII equivalent into character and then concatenates it with the intitial string
    }
    return(de);
}

void encode_display(String en)//displays the code
{
    int i,l;
    char ic;
    System.out.println("YOUR ENCODED MESSAGE IS :");
    l=en.length();
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        ic=en.charAt(i);
        if(ic=='1')//for every 'one' it will print '.'(dot)
        {
             System.out.print(".");
        }
        else if(ic=='0')//for every 'zero' it will print ' '(space)
        {
             System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}

void decode_display(String de)
{
    System.out.println(de);
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    char ch;

    ed2 ed = new ed2();

    System.out.println("PRESS 'E' TO ENCODE A MESSAGE OR PRESS 'D' TO DECODE A MESSAGE");
    ch = (char)obj.read();

    if((ch=='e')||(ch=='E'))
    {
        ed.encode();
    }
    else if((ch=='d')||(ch=='D'))
    {
        ed.decode();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where you say "ASCII" and use 7 bits, it should be "UTF-16 code-unit" and 16 bits. Try it with "[€](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm)"; It should look like 0010000010101100.

Comment: I din't say 7 "bits", I said that the "length" would be 7. If each individual binary-string would be of different lengths, how would the decoder know what length of code it has to extract from the code entered by the user. Thus, to make it a little easy, for the decoder, it always extracts a code of 'length' 7. This is done by adding required number of zeroes before the binary-string of each letter, since adding any number of zeroes before a binary number does not change its value.

Comment: My point is that `char` is 16 bits. If only the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/c_0000.html) are to be handled then throw an exception when `ic > '\u007F'`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't know the format of a file then you have data loss.**

The question is then how to prevent missing that vital "metadata". The typical way is through protocols and specifications.

You can, in some cases, determine that a file has byte values or sequences that would be invalid in certain encodings, for example 0x80 is not valid ASCII and 0xE2 0x20 is not valid UTF-8. There are libraries for this type of guessing. However, CP437 can never be ruled out; So, every file can be considered a text file, just as every file can be considered a sequence of values 0-255 or -128 to 127, and every file with an even number of bytes can be considered....

There are protocol analyzers that interpret bytes according to various nested protocols, such as Wireshark, and there are Hex editors that show both bytes and attempted conversion to characters. Some hex editors are pretty sophisticated with features like find by bytes, find by text, allow you to describe a protocol and apply it to portions of the file. (Old disk sector editors are an example.)

The bottom line is that this is reverse engineering and hopefully you wouldn't need to do it.

BTW—65 is the letter A in many, many encodings; not just ASCII.